# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "80,80" or "443,443" in Swagger

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, netflix-zuul

We are using Spring Boot, Swagger and Zuul API gateway in our application and when we try to access swagger documentation. We get java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "80,80" exception.

We found that the root cause was due to multiple port details passed as comma separated array hence  it is just trying to parse that header value without actually fetch the one value from that array.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved by using the ***Springfox 2.9.2*** version instead of Springfox 2.6.1 version.